# Saved Image base64 is wrong

Tags: android, database, base64

i am trying to save some images to a web server. So what I doe is I convert my file in android to Base64 string, send it to my server and save the Base64 string in my database. When I need, I read the string from that database and decode it. But there is some problem with my image because the image is all grey.

This is my code to convert the image to base64:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), options);
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;


if (imageWidth > widthPixels) {
    myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, byteArrayOutputStream);
} else {
    myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                                }

byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Then I send the string "encoded" to the server and save it in the database.

And this is part of my image saved in the server

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDABALDA4MChAODQ4SERATGCgaGBYWGDEjJR0oOjM9PDkz
ODdASFxOQERXRTc4UG1RV19iZ2hnPk1xeXBkeFxlZ2P/2wBDARESEhgVGC8aGi9jQjhCY2NjY2Nj

for some reason there are some "\n" and I think that this is causing my problem. I have already tried to remove them with a replaceAll but didn't worked.

This is the output I get

[image]

This is my database structure:

[image]

I'm saving the encoded 64base image as a string in the column caled "imagemBase". Could the problem be in the type or in the codification that i'm using?

Comment: You may want to try Base64.NO_WRAP

Answer (score 0):

I using this methods an worked for me:

```
public static String encodeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap != null) {
        bitmap = resize(bitmap, 800, 800);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] byteArrayImage = baos.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
    return null;
}

public static Bitmap decodeBitmap(String encodedImage) {
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
}

public static Bitmap resize(Bitmap image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    if (maxHeight > 0 && maxWidth > 0) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        float ratioBitmap = (float) width / (float) height;
        float ratioMax = (float) maxWidth / (float) maxHeight;

        int finalWidth = maxWidth;
        int finalHeight = maxHeight;
        if (ratioMax > ratioBitmap) {
            finalWidth = (int) ((float) maxHeight * ratioBitmap);
        } else {
            finalHeight = (int) ((float) maxWidth / ratioBitmap);
        }
        image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, finalWidth, finalHeight, true);
        return image;
    } else {
        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saving the base64 image to a server with this code?

Comment: @Manuel_Rodrigues yse. i copied this codes from my working project.

Comment: I have tried the code but got the same result. The images are saved in the server but whne I try to receive them from the server the output is the same as the one in the image I sent in my question.

Comment: maybe your problem is in server side.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. When I converted the image to base64 the string that I received hade some + cahrs in it and for some reason when I sent it to the server the + was replaced with a blank space. I needed to make a replace on the php file where I replaced all black spaces with the + character before saving the string in the database.